# WPF: Nested collection binding

Tags: binding

My application shows a question and possible answers on that question. Now I want to give the correct answer (specified in the "CorrectAnswer" property) a green color. Can someone help me? Thanks.

```
public class Exercise
{
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public int CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
    public Answer[] Answers { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Answer
{
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

XAML:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=QuestionText}"></Label>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Answers}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=AnswerText}"></Label>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some idea on `ValueConverter` in WPF, better make use of that. That will give you a lot of flexibility and easy to implement. Please let me know, if you still have some doubt.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have a solution. I've used the MultiValueConverter.